# Bulk mailing in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, bulk-mail

We have a site running in ASP.NET 4.0 and a dedicated Windows Server 2008R2.

So after a user successfully registers to the website, we use Facebook like friend finder and give the user an option to import friends from Facebook, Gmail, Yahoo! and / or Hotmail if they want that.  And after they have selected the friends they want to mail, we send those friends invitations. As we cannot make the user wait until all the invitations are sent, we need another mechanism to do that. We are thinking of

1. [Using a service like MailChimp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3750536/17447)
2. Using MSMQ for sending mails
3. Using a Windows Service to retrieve ids from a database and send them?

On our research we found out that 2 and 3 may result in the SMTP Server being blacklisted and it will also cause the server load to increase. Our questions are

1. Are those assumptions correct?
2. Is MailChimp or services like that the way to go?
3. Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: So someone signs up for your service, then you spam all their friends by email?

Comment: @cjk: we are not talking about business logic here. :) Pal its just a friend finder. also we are asking them to sign in via oauth to all third party providers(if they want) and then asking them to check the friends they want to invite (again if they want). fair enough?